# HTML form - value depends on two different drop-down menus

Tags: javascript, forms, drop-down-menu

Hello javascript experts!

I'm a novice here, trying to create a script to add up membership fees on a website (I'm a volunteer). Any help is greatly appreciated.

I used this website: http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-calculator-script.phtml to set up my html.

It worked just fine  (I set up 3 functions, one to calculate the membership price, another for the postage and the other the total amount due - I have not included them below but know they work fine).

UNTIL I realized that the value of postage (which I had calculated only using the first drop-down menu: id=country) was also dependant on the amount in the second drop down menu (the second drop-down menu's id: membership_type). That is to say, the postage is not only determined by country but also by membership type. I tried to set up a script that would vary the value of the postage depending on the value of the membership type but it isn't working.

I'm not a coder as you can tell so I've spent a lot of time looking for the correct way to do this but have come to a deadend....

---

```
    var membership_prices = new Array();
    membership_prices["regular"]=40;
    membership_prices["student"]=24;
    membership_prices["emeritus"]=24;
    membership_prices["regularplus"]=62;
    membership_prices["studentplus"]=46;
    membership_prices["emeritusplus"]=46;

    var extra_postage_cost = new Array();
    extra_postage_cost["USA"]=0;
    extra_postage_cost["Canada"]=0;

    <!-- this is the part that needs work: Edited since original post -->
       extra_postage_cost["Other_Country"]
   if (document.getElementById('membership_type').value =="regular")
       extra_postage_cost["Other_Country"]=8;
   else if (document.getElementById('membership_type').value =="student")
       extra_postage_cost["Other_Country"]=8;
   else if (document.getElementById('membership_type').value =="emeritus")
       extra_postage_cost["Other_Country"]=8; 
   else if (document.getElementById('membership_type').value =="regularplus")
       extra_postage_cost["Other_Country"]=16;
   else if (document.getElementById('membership_type').value =="studentplus")
       extra_postage_cost["Other_Country"]=16;
   else if (document.getElementById('membership_type').value =="emeritusplus")
       extra_postage_cost["Other_Country"]=16;
   else 
       extra_postage_cost["Other_Country"]=0;
   <!-- end of what I believe needs work -->
```

Here is the rest of the code:

```
    function getMembershipPrice ()
        {
        var membershipPrice=0;
        var theForm = document.forms["membershipform"];
        var selectedMembership = theForm.elements["membership_type"];
        membershipPrice = membership_prices[selectedMembership.value];
        return membershipPrice;
        }

    function getExtraPostagePrice ()
        {
        var extraPostagePrice = 0;
        var theForm = document.forms["membershipform"];
        var selectedPostage = theForm.elements["country"];
        extraPostagePrice = extra_postage_cost[selectedPostage.value];
        return extraPostagePrice;
        }

    function getAmountDue()
        {
        var amountDue = getMembershipPrice() + getExtraPostagePrice();
        document.getElementById('amountDue').innerHTML ="Amount Due $"+amountDue;
        }
```

In the drop-down menus themselves I have this kind of code inside the brackets for each drop-down menu:

```
   select name="membership_type" id="membership_type" onchange="getAmountDue()"
   select name="country" id="country" onchange="getAmountDue()"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the country drop down is defaulted to USA. If this is the case, simply add an "onchange" event listener to the dropdowns that call a function to update the extra charge.

So instead of having an array object for extra postage, just have a variable extraPostage initially set to zero and update it when the drop downs change.

```
    var extraPostage = 0;

    function onSelectChange(){
      var countrySelect = document.getElementById('countrySelect'); 
      var typeSelect = document.getElementById('membership_type');
      if(countrySelect.value != "Other Country"){
        extraPostage = 0;
        return;
      }
      else{
        var type = typeSelect.value;
        switch(type){
          case "regular":
            extraPostage = 8;
            break;
          case "student":
            extraPostage = 8;
            break;
          case "emeritus":
            extragPostage = 8;
            break;
          //keep going for each different possibility
        }

    }
```

Comment: I think actually that this may have hit the nail on the head. I guess what I am trying to do should be taken care of by the function that computes the postage price, not by an elaborate array.

Comment: I'm still have a few questions though. At the end, don't I need the function to "return extraPostage"? (To send this value to my function that adds the postage cost to the membership cost)
If so, after that last bracket from the else statement I see above, do I need a ";" or do I just type return extraPostage; before the final function closing bracket? I've tried this but it doesn't seem to be working...

Comment: I figured it out!
I had to add to add "return extraPostage" after each amount (e.g. extraPostage=8; return extraPostage;). I also named the function above "getExtraPostagePrice" so it worked with the function that totalled the two amounts.
NOW IT WORKS! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

You did good for being a self-proclaimed amateur. I think that you can probably more easily solve your problem with a multi-dimensional array so you can associate the membership prices with the corresponding postage:

```
var MEMBERSHIP = 0;
var POSTAGE = 1;

var membership_prices = new Array();
membership_prices["regular"] = [40, 8];
membership_prices["student"] = [24, 8];
membership_prices["emeritus"] = [24, 8];
membership_prices["regularplus"] = [62, 16];
membership_prices["studentplus"] = [46, 16];
membership_prices["emeritusplus"] = [46, 16];
```

Now, to access the membership price and postage price, if other country is selected, you can simply run:

```
membership_prices["regular"][MEMBERSHIP]   // returns 40
membership_prices["regular"][POSTAGE]      // returns 8
```

I used MEMBERSHIP and POSTAGE instead of 0 and 1 so it might make your code more readable when you're getting the values for the membership and the posting. Or if you prefer, you can simply access the inner array with the 0 and 1:

```
membership_prices["regular"][0]   // returns 40
membership_prices["regular"][1]      // returns 8
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you're trying to do it looks like you were on the right track, but needed to invert how you're thinking about the logic in relation to the variable. You also had a few extra `"`s and `{}`s.

Try this in place of the code below `<!-- this is the part that needs work: -->`.

```
if (document.getElementById('membership_type').value =="regular")
    extra_postage_cost["Other_Country"]= 8;
else if (document.getElementById('membership_type').value =="student")
    extra_postage_cost["Other_Country"]= 8;
else if (document.getElementById('membership_type').value =="emeritus")
    extra_postage_cost["Other_Country"]= 8; 
else if (document.getElementById('membership_type').value =="regularplus")
    extra_postage_cost["Other_Country"]= 16;
else if (document.getElementById('membership_type').value =="studentplus")
    extra_postage_cost["Other_Country"]= 16;
else if (document.getElementById('membership_type').value =="emeritusplus")
    extra_postage_cost["Other_Country"]= 16;
else 
    extra_postage_cost["Other_Country"]= 0;
```

Comment: Don't forget `.value` after each of the `document.getElementByID()`s; otherwise, you'll get the actual DOM element, not the string value.  Also, the first line is missing an = (should be `==`).

Comment: Ah, thanks. Overlooked that while editing the logic. Edited my answer.

Comment: I'm overwhelmed by everyone's generosity! 

I'm going to try this one first since it fits better with my code for the moment. 

I'm also going to edit code at the top so you can see how it looks now... At present I get a $NaN error

Comment: Actually, I don't get $NaN when I've selected USA or Canada

Comment: So everything works now except the "other country" part. The membership price and extra postage price add together when the extra postage is zero. But the "other country" part of the code is still missing something (please see the top of the post where I updated how my code now looks)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var otherCountryPostageCost = 0,
    membershipType = document.getElementById('membership_type');

if (membershipType == "regular" || membershipType == "student" || membershipType == "emeritus"){
  otherCountryPostageCost = 8;
} else if (membershipType == "regularplus" || membershipType == "emeritusplus") {
  otherCountryPostageCost = 16;
}

extra_postage_cost["Other_Country"] = otherCountryPostageCost;
```

Comment: The problem is, this doesn't take into account that a country other than "other country" could be selected...

Answer (score 0):

I'm a novice too :) I thought for some time the most readable way of adding other countries' extra postage, assuming there will be many, and concluded with the following:

`extra_postage_cost["Country"] = [ (regular), (student), (emeritus) ]`

Where each value in parentheses is a number. For example:

`extra_postage_cost["Ostia"] = [10, 20, 30, 60, 60, 30];`

For this to work we need to define some variables and functions. The idea is to link the numerical order of a type (student, regular) in `membership_types` to the numerical position in each of the extra postage cost arrays.

```
  membership_types = ["regular", "student", "emeritus", 
    "regularplus", "studentplus", "emeritusplus"];

  function membership_index(m_type) {
    var index = -1;
    for(var i = 0; i < membership_types.length; i++) {
      if(m_type == membership_types[i]) {
        index = i;
      }
    }
    return index;
  }
```

Then when retrieving, it's kinda ugly :( but we want to first address the country, then the numerical position for the cost, that matches the membership type.

```
extraPostage = extra_postage_cost[whichCountry][membership_index(whichMembership)];
```

The result is here : http://jsfiddle.net/TgdEW/

p.s. I think technically you're not creating arrays, but objects, so I declare `variable_name = {}`

Comment: Thank you for your detailed code. What I ultimately want to have though is a total cost for the new member. I want the membership type cost and the possible extra postage cost (depending on country selected) added in a total at the bottom.